# React dependencies in Sublime Text

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner in React and has been working with the CDN links so far, I decided to remove these links and install the dependencies as it is better to work with, so I have tried to install the dependencies as instructed in the official website with npm install, and did so in my project repository, and after importing from react and react-dom the JS script doesn't work at all, and the console shows no errors, I tried a lot of fixes (including changing the source from index.js to index.pack.js), I also tried installing react using package control of Sublime Text, but nothing worked.
I don't think it's a code problem, but here are the index.html and index.js files :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//import React from 'react'
//import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
const React = require("react");
const ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
const element = <h1 className="header">This is JSX</h1>
console.log(element)

ReactDOM.render(
    element,
     document.getElementById("root")
    )
```

The css folder and files are all in the correct place and so is the index.js so it's not a path error, I think it's most likely a dependency error but it can be something else, does anyone have an idea on how to fix this, thanks in advance!

Comment: As purely a text editor, Sublime isn't the cause of your issue here. It's NodeJS/your browser that are responsible for running the code that you write. It may also be worth mentioning that Package Control is for installing extension packages that augment the functionality of Sublime Text; at best the only thing you're going to add are functionalities that make it easier for you to edit your React code.

Comment: I would recommend using [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started) if you are just getting started with React. This will setup a boilerplate React application for you with all the packaging and build processes setup for you. Trying to write your own build script via webpack or something similar can be very frustrating for even the most fluent developers :) If you do want to go that manual route, [following tutorials like this may be of interest](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/create-a-react-app-from-scratch-in-2021-8e9948602e9c) or Google "React App from Scratch"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply as I have kinda solved the problem on the spot :D, indeed Create React App was the way to go, it builds the application nicely and it manages dependecies as well. Thanks for your answers !